# WPF ReactiveUI application crashes after 30 min inactive

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

Have someone faced such issue on WPF application using ReactiveUI framework.
If application stay inactive for about 30 minutes and after that we try to continue working with it again it crashes with:

2018-03-30 06:09:44.1253 ERROR DispatcherUnhandledException;
An object implementing IHandleObservableErrors (often a ReactiveCommand or ObservableAsPropertyHelper) has errored, thereby breaking its observable pipeline. To prevent this, ensure the pipeline does not error, or Subscribe to the ThrownExceptions property of the object in question to handle the erroneous case.

I'm using Binding in the xaml.cs backend file like:

```
this.WhenActivated(
    disposables =>
    {
        this.Bind(…)
            .DisposeWith(disposables);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough code or information to properly troubleshoot but one of your observables or tasks are throwing an exception and you aren't handling it. Hook the default exception handler for additional insights and enable stop on first chance exceptions in Visual Studio.

- https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/default-exception-handler/
- https://reactiveui.net/docs/guidelines/debugging/disable-just-my-code

ps; do you have a subscription to your ReactiveCommand.ThrownExceptions? If not - add one.